# Metalsmith template of template

Tags: metalsmith

Is it possible to use templates that extend each other?

Say, I have these files:

**base.html**:

```
<html><head>...<head><body>{{{ contents }}}</body></html>
```

**threeColumns.html**:

```
---
layout: base.html
---
<div class="three-cols-row">
   <div class="first col">
      {{> nav}}
   </div>
   <div class="second col">
       {{{ contents }}}
   </div>
   <div class="third col">
      {{> aside}}
   </div>
</div>
```

**somePost.html**:

```
---
layout: threeColumns.html
---

My awesome blogbost
```

**Desired output**:

```
<html><head>...<head>
    <body>
        <div class="three-cols-row">
           <div class="first col">
              NAV CONTENT
           </div>
            <div class="second col">
               My awesome blogbost
           </div>
           <div class="third col">
              ASIDE CONTENT
           </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using metalsmith-layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, but not exactly in the way that you want to.

Metalsmith-layouts is meant to be a shim for [template inheritance](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/#inheritance) for languages that don't natively support it, like handlebars. To make this possible it parses the files that you pass to it, `somePost.html` in this case, and looks for a `layout` key in the front-matter. After that it processes the chosen layout, `threeColumns.html`, by passing `somePost.html` to `threeColumns.html` as the variable `contents`.

At that point the file is rendered with your chosen engine by [consolidate](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/). So the `layout` key, which is specific to `metalsmith-layouts` no longer works in `threeColumns.html` because metalsmith-layouts doesn't process it. At this point the file is being processed by consolidate.

What you **can** do is use a language that natively supports template inheritance, like swig. Then you could do:

**build.js**

```js
/**
 * Dependencies
 */
var filenames = require('metalsmith-filenames');
var layouts = require('metalsmith-layouts');
var metalsmith = require('metalsmith');

/**
 * Build
 */
metalsmith(__dirname)
  .use(filenames()) // Necessary for extends and includes
  .use(layouts('swig'))

  .build(function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

**src/somePost.swig**

```swig
---
layout: threeColumns.swig
---
<p>My awesome blogpost</p>
```

**layouts/threeColumns.swig**

```swig
{% extends "base.swig" %}

{% block body %}
<div class="three-cols-row">
   <div class="first col">
      {% include "nav.swig" %}
   </div>
   <div class="second col">
       {{ contents | safe }}
   </div>
   <div class="third col">
      {% include "aside.swig" %}
   </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**layouts/base.swig**

```swig
<html>
  <head><head>
  <body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**layouts/nav.swig**

```swig
<nav>Navigation</nav>
```

**layouts/aside.swig**

```swig
<aside>Aside content</aside>
```

If you then run `node build.js` from the command line, it'll build it into a single page.

Comment: Well, I decided against SWIG, but I will accept this answer as reference for other people.

Comment: @AliOk I understand. You don't have to use swig btw., any language that natively supports template inheritance will do.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Handlebars as your metalsmith template engine. That means you'll need to register your partials.

Something Like:

```
var contents = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/templates/partials/" + fileName).toString();
Handlebars.registerPartial(partialTemplateName, contents);
```

You're probably going to have multiple partials so you could use `fs.readdirSync('templates/partials');` to get all the files and then wrap this in a loop for each file.